# Trying to search for a file in Python 3.7, but can't get out of current working directory

Tags: python

Playing around with Python and trying to use os.walk() to search for files around my drives:

```
import os

def find_files(filename, search_path):
    result = []
    for root, dir, files in os.walk(search_path, topdown=False):
        print('Root: ' + root)
        print(dir)
        if filename in files:
            result.append((os.path.join(root, filename)))
    return result
```

When I run the function, it doesn't matter what I put in the search_path, it just goes to the current working directory instead, like os.walk is ignoring everything except the Python directory. Am I doing something wrong?

Using PyCharm 2019 2.5 Community for an IDE and then I tested it in the Python 3.7 terminal and got the same thing.

Comment: Could you show an example of what you put for `search_path`? How do you know it's "going to" the CWD? (And have you verified that the CWD is what you think it is?) You are aware of the distinction between absolute and relative paths I hope?

Comment: I just ran this and it worked fine with several different values for `search_path`

Comment: Yes, the call I was using was: ```print(find_files("Snowflake_Solutions.txt", "C:"))```. I went back around after I got results and checked, because I thought a root of "C:\" would show things like "Program Files" and other such Windows-esque file folders. Instead, I got ".idea" and "venv" which walked down to other folders in the default Python CWD. And I am; from what I read on os.walk, I thought setting the path to "C:" would set it to the "C:" main folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is correct - it works fine here on Windows and Python 3.8.2. I suspect you're not passing the path correctly - you say in your comment you tried `"C:"`. That is not the path to the C drive, you want `"C:\\"`.

Comment: Yep, just tried it with an escape character to set the slash properly and off it went. Thanks! I freely admit that I was a full numpty on that.